# BinarySearch unable to find specific elements in String [ ]

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

The name of a novel and its assigned integer-code is stored in a sorted array so that each even index (including 0) contains a code and each odd index contains a title:

> [1, Tom Sawyer, 2, Black Beauty, 3, Treasure Island]

Currently, I've implemented a BinarySearch method which takes a user-inputted code and outputs the corresponding title if it exists. It works, unless the user inputs:

- 100 (last code in the array)
- 2, 6, or 10; but **works** for 1

  ```
  public static String binarySearch(String [] bookList, int left, int right, String code)
  {

  /* bookList - sorted array 
   * left - leftmost index
   * right - rightmost index
   * code - item to look for
   */

   int middle;

   if (left > right) {
       return "left>right";
   }

   middle = (left + right)/2;
   /*set middle to nearest even offset (all # are in  even position)*/
   middle += middle & 1;

   if (bookList[middle].equals(code)) {
          return bookList[middle + 1];
   }

   if (code.compareTo(bookList[middle]) < 0) {
      return binarySearch(bookList, left, middle - 1, code);
   }

   return binarySearch(bookList, middle + 2, right, code);         
  }
  ```

The entire contents of the array can be found [here](https://hdsb.elearningontario.ca/content/enforced/7823458-EL_CS_ICS4UO-01_893675_1516Sem2/ICS4U%20(Java)PU03/ICS4U%20(Java)PU03A03/docs/Booklist.txt?_&d2lSessionVal=TC7EUCF6jOThRj7nI4bkZ9jrC&ou=7823458)

Comment: Why do you compare the `code` (which is a number) as `String`? What happens if you compare "2" and "11"? Convert it to `int` and then compare.

Comment: The lexicograpical order of numbers as strings is - 1,10,11,12, ..., 19, 100, 2, 20, 21... so if you treat your codes as strings, the array is not sorted.

Comment: @TDG I'd gladly accept your comment as the answer to my unintelligent question.

Comment: 1. Test it befroe you accept it. 2. This is not unintelligent question. You've done effort, tried and learned a new thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your codes are strings that represent numbers. Since you compare them as strings, the lexicographical order is 1, 10, 11, 12, ..., 19, 100, 2, 20, 21... so the array is not sorted as you might think.
What you should do is parse the code as an `int` -

```
int bookCode = Integer.parseInt(code);
```

and then compare -

```
if Integer.parseIntbookList[middle] < bookCode
//do something
```